# Type is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

trying to use dynamically-created Themes and ThemeKeys and create a new object with properties that exist within the ThemeKeys. However, I get this error that I couldn't understand why.

```
// Type 'ThemeKeys' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

Passing `any` to `theme` solves the issue but really want to understand the root cause here. Thanks in advance!

```
   interface Themes {
      [key: string]: ThemeKeys;
    }
    
    interface ThemeKeys {
      [key: string]: string|number;
    }

    const p = (theme:Themes, properties:string|string[])=>{

    const result={}


  if (Array.isArray(properties)) {
    properties.forEach(property => {
      const value = lodash.get(theme, `${property}.${key}`);
      if (value != null) {
        result[property as keyof typeof result] = value; // Type 'ThemeKeys' is not assignable to type 'string'.
      }
    });
  }
}
```